# Audio file not play from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, avaudioplayer

I am playing audio file from server but it is not playing if i play local file then it plays here is my code.

```
    //NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/1.mp3"];


NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);             
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `MPMoviePlayerController` instead of `AVAudioPlayer`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/1.mp3"];


mv = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
mv.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
[self.view addSubview:mv.view];
[mv play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to solve your problem...

```
NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/productivo/1.mp3]];
NSError *error;

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
audioPlayer.volume = 1.0f;
[audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]); 
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```